# How to recover deleted SQL server in Azure?

Tags: azure, data-recovery

I mistakenly deleted the database server. I need help. I made the mistake of creating a new server with the same name, will it be possible to recover a database?

I have previous resource name data and subscription ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can raise a support request and Microsoft may be able to restore the server if it has not been a significant period of time.